# Gmail not recognizing MX record

Tags: email, sendgrid

I'm attempting to utilize SendGrid's inbound parse feature which parses any email sent to a specific subdomain and posts the data to an endpoint you provide.

This requires setting an MX record for your subdomain and pointing it at the SendGrid server.

I added the record in my DNS management and when I run `dig mx` it successfully shows the record

```
~ dig mx email.2x4game.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> mx email.2x4game.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31172
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;email.2x4game.com.     IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
email.2x4game.com.  3600    IN  MX  10 mx.sendgrid.net.
```

However, when I try to send an email to an address at the subdomain via Gmail, the email bounces and the error says

```
DNS Error: DNS type 'mx' lookup of email.2x4game.com responded with code NXDOMAIN Domain name not found: email.2x4game.com
```

Is there some additional step that I'm missing to be able to send emails to this subdomain?

Comment: How long have you waited after adding the record? DNS can take time to settle.

Comment: @tadman Looks like you were right. I assumed that because the dig command showed the record at the time, that it should always be recognized. It looks like now that some time has passed, Gmail is recognizing it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to wait some time. After waiting 24+ hours, I am able to send emails to the subdomain and SendGrid is detecting them accordingly.

Comment: The amount of time it takes to effect a change can be dictated by the record's TTL, or "Time to Live", which impacts how long it is cached. For an MX record, consider 3600s, though some systems default to days or even a week.